# can't find profile with id=

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I have a `user` model created with devise and a `profile` model, everything works fine. I'm trying to create a link for a user to be able to go to his profile and edit the profile

```
<li><%= link_to "Profile", edit_profile_path(current_user) %></li>
```

I get an error: `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in ProfilesController#show`

The user `has_one :profile`, all associations are linked correctly and data is being saved as expected with `user_id` column in `profile` model.

and its telling me the error is here:

```
    def set_profile
      @profile = Profile.find(params[:id])
    end
```

I have been trying to figure this out but have had no luck?

profile_controller.rb:

```
class ProfilesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_profile, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :authenticate_user!, only: [:show, :new, :edit, :create, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /profiles
  # GET /profiles.json
  def index
    @profiles = Profile.all
  end

  # GET /profiles/1
  # GET /profiles/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /profiles/new
  def new
    @profile = current_user.build_profile
  end

  # GET /profiles/1/edit
  def edit

  end

  # POST /profiles
  # POST /profiles.json
  def create
    @profile = current_user.build_profile(profile_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @profile.save
        format.html { redirect_to @profile, notice: 'Profile was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @profile }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @profile.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /profiles/1
  # PATCH/PUT /profiles/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @profile.update(profile_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @profile, notice: 'Profile was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @profile }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @profile.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /profiles/1
  # DELETE /profiles/1.json
  def destroy
    @profile.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to profiles_url, notice: 'Profile was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_profile
      @profile = Profile.find_by(user_id: params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def profile_params
      params.require(:profile).permit(:bio, :user_id, educations_attributes: [:id, :university, :course, :yearCompleted, :_destroy])
    end
end
```

routes:

```
  resources :profiles
  devise_for :users, controllers: {registrations: "registrations"}
  get 'home/index'
  root 'home#index'
```

**UPDATED**

I changed:

```
def set_profile
  @profile = Profile.find(params[:id])
end
```

To

```
def set_profile
  @profile = Profile.find_by(user_id: params[:id])
end
```

which takes me to the correct edit view for the user, but when i click update, it throws an error: undefined method `update' for nil:NilClass

Comment: Please show the rest of your controller. The error is caused because params[:id] is nil. Also please show your routes file.

Comment: profile is a separate object, yet you use user id for the url generation. Of course, it's not found. Pass profile id instead.

Comment: I have added my profile_controller and routes fill to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using

```
edit_profile_path(current_user)
```

params[:id] is the current_users id. Try something like

```
@profile = Profile.find_by(user_id: params[:id])
```

#### Update

It might make more sense to use a singular resource for a users profile. You can read further information on singular resources in the Rails guides: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#singular-resources

Routes file:

```
ressource :profile
```

Simplified controller:

```
class ProfilesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  before_action :load_profile

  def show; end

  def edit; end

  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @profile.update(profile_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @profile, notice: 'Profile was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @profile }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @profile.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  private

    def load_profile
      @profile = current_user.profile || current_user.build_profile
    end

    def profile_params
      params.require(:profile).permit(:bio, :user_id, educations_attributes: [:id, :university, :course, :yearCompleted, :_destroy])
    end
end
```

Example link to the edit profile page: `<li><%= link_to "Profile", edit_profile_path %></li>`

Comment: How do you know that it is `user_id`, and not `id`?

Comment: @BilalMaqsood: have you read the question? "data is being saved as expected with user_id column in profile model"

Comment: This works!, it takes me to the correct edit page, but when i click update throws an error: undefined method `update' for nil:NilClass